# mysql query array counter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Apologies if I have the terminology wrong.

I have a for loop in php which operates a mysql query...

```
for ($i = 0; $i <count($user_id_pc); $i++) 
{
$query2 = " SELECT job_title, job_info FROM job_description WHERE  postcode_ss = '$user_id_pc[$i]'";

$job_data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);

$job_results = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($job_data))
        {
            array_push($job_results, $row);
        }

}
```

The results that are given when I insert a...

`print_r ($job_results);`

> On screen -> Array()

If I change the query from `$user_id_pc[$i]` to `$user_id_pc[14]` for example I receive one set of results.

If I include this code after the query and inside the for loop

```
echo $i;
echo $user_id_pc[$i] . "<br>";
```

I receive the number the counter `$i` is on followed by the data inside the array for that counter position.

I am not sure why the array `$job_results` is empty from the query using the counter `$i` but not if I enter the number manually?

Is it a special character I need to escape?

The full code

```
        <?php
print_r ($user_id_pc);

  //Select all columns to see if user has a profile
     $query = "SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";

      //If the user has an empty profile direct them to the home page

  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) 
    {
        echo '<br><div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"><h3>Your appear not to be logged on please visit the<a href="index.php"> home page</a> to log on or register. <em>Thank you.</em></h3></div>';
    }
//Select data from user and asign them to variables
    else
    {
          $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) 
      {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
          $cw_job_name = $row['job_description'];
          $cw_rate = $row['hourly_rate'];
          $job_mileage = $row['mileage'];
          $job_postcode = $row['postcode'];
          $response_id = $row['user_profile_id'];
      }
    }


    for ($i = 0; $i <count($user_id_pc); $i++) 
        {
            $query2 = " SELECT job_title, job_info FROM job_description WHERE  postcode_ss = '{$user_id_pc[$i]}'";                                        
    $job_data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
    $job_results = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($job_data))
            {
                array_push($job_results, $row);
            }

    echo $i;
?>
<br>
<?php

}
print ($query2);
print $user_id_pc[$i];
         ?>
```

Comment: try this $query2 = " SELECT job_title, job_info FROM job_description WHERE  postcode_ss = '".$user_id_pc[$i]."'";

Comment: query inside loop is not good way to getting thing done, there is another way to do it..... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is primarily a syntax error, the correct syntax should be:

```
$query2 = " SELECT job_title, job_info FROM job_description WHERE  postcode_ss = '{$user_id_pc[$i]}'";
```

Note that this is correct syntax but still wrong!! For two reasons the first is that it's almost always better (faster, more efficient, takes less resources) to do a join or a subquery or a simple IN(array) type query rather than to loop and query multiple times.

The second issue is that passing parameters in this manner leave your vulnerable to sql injection. You should use prepared statements.

**The correct way**

```
if(count($user_id_pc)) {
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_prepare(" SELECT job_title, job_info FROM job_description WHERE  postcode_ss = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", "'" . implode("','",$user_id_pc) . "'");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Note that the for loop has been replaced by a simple if

Comment: Hi, I tried the curly braces and still get the same results. I am teaching myself code at the moment and am unsure of what prepared statements are. Thanks anyway

Comment: curly braces works. Please print out $query2 and see what you get (and post as a comment if it's not what you expected it to be).

Comment: Also note that as I have mentioned, using this approach is very very wrong.

Comment: Using this query... $query2 = " SELECT job_title, job_info FROM job_description WHERE  postcode_ss = '{$user_id_pc[$i]}'";            
I receive this on screen if I use a print_r          Array ( ) ...Thanks

Comment: that's is not what I am asking, I am asking you to do print ($query2)

Comment: this is the result of print ($query2) 
SELECT job_title, job_info FROM job_description WHERE postcode_ss = 'SO53'

Comment: also print $user_id_pc[$i]

Comment: print $user_id_pc[$i] displays no results

Comment: is this sorted out now? Sorry I missed your last comment if `print $user_id_pc[$i]` doesn't show an results that means your array isn't what you expected it to be

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I'm reading up on prepared statements as you suggested to change my query. I still cant work out why the array $user_id_pc[$i] is empty as it works ok in a foreach loop and works if I enter the counter number manually???. I'm new to this forum and I see I can awarded badges??? shall I do this for you???

Comment: Hard to figure out why your `user_id_pc[$i]` is empty without seeing what it's content is or how you generate it. If you edit the question and the lines above the current bit of code it might become guessable.

Comment: You need to read up on SQL JOINs all this code can be replaced by a few lines without all this complexity and it will be much faster too

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the query variable, instead of:

```
$query2 = " SELECT job_title, job_info FROM job_description WHERE  postcode_ss = '$user_id_pc[$i]'"
```

have you tried this:

```
$query2 = " SELECT job_title, job_info FROM job_description WHERE  postcode_ss = '" . $user_id_pc[$i] . "' ";
```

And another thing, try something different like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($job_data))
    {
        $job_results[] = array("job_title" => $row["job_title"], "job_info" => $row["job_info");
    }
```

Then try to print the values.

Comment: Hi, I've tried the 2 other codes and I still have the same results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I like **[foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)**, so your working code is:

```
<?php

 // To store the result
 $job_results = [];

 foreach($user_id_pc as $id ){
   // selecting matching rows   
   $query2 ="SELECT job_title, job_info FROM job_description WHERE postcode_ss = '".$id."'";
   $job_data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
   // checking if query fetch any result
   if(mysqli_num_rows($job_data)){
      // fetching the result
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($job_data)){
        // storing resulting row
        $job_results[] = $row;
     }
   }
}
// to print the result
var_dump($job_results);
```